# What is the algorithm of TreeNode.Nodes.ContainsKey

Tags: c#, treenode

I am confused about `TreeNode.Nodes.ContainsKey(string key)` if  its searching recursively in its childs for the key, or just searches in its childs only using a regular for loop.
If it recursively searches about the key, is there is a method to search only in its childs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeNodeCollection.cs,382), `ContainsKey` does the following:

```
    public virtual bool ContainsKey(string key) {
       return IsValidIndex(IndexOfKey(key)); 
    }
```

And that method does:

```
    public virtual int  IndexOfKey(String key) {
        // Step 0 - Arg validation
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)){
            return -1; // we dont support empty or null keys.
        }

        // step 1 - check the last cached item
        if (IsValidIndex(lastAccessedIndex))
        {
            if (WindowsFormsUtils.SafeCompareStrings(this[lastAccessedIndex].Name, key, /* ignoreCase = */ true)) {
                return lastAccessedIndex;
            }
        }

        // step 2 - search for the item
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i ++) {
            if (WindowsFormsUtils.SafeCompareStrings(this[i].Name, key, /* ignoreCase = */ true)) {
                lastAccessedIndex = i;
                return i;
            }
        }

        // step 3 - we didn't find it.  Invalidate the last accessed index and return -1.
        lastAccessedIndex = -1;
        return -1;
    }

    private bool IsValidIndex(int index) {
        return ((index >= 0) && (index < this.Count));
    }
```

So it appears it just tries to find the index for the key, and if it's valid then that means the key must exist.

Answer (score 1):

Code is simple to write to get first node with key.  Use root = true so code doesn't check top level node.  Code can be used with any not not just root of treeview.

```
       public KeyValuePair<Boolean, TreeNode> SearchChildren(TreeNode node, string key, Boolean root)
        {
            if (!root)
            {
                if(node.Nodes.ContainsKey(key)) return new KeyValuePair<bool, TreeNode>(true, node.Nodes[key]);
            }

            foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
            {
                if (child.Nodes != null)
                {
                    KeyValuePair<Boolean, TreeNode> results = SearchChildren(child, key, false);
                    if (results.Key)
                    {
                        return results;
                    }

                }
            }
            return new KeyValuePair<bool, TreeNode>(false, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`TreeNode.Nodes.ContainsKey(string key)` only searches the for the `key` in the child nodes which are direct descendents of the `TreeNode`, and does not recursively check child nodes.

The `Nodes` property of `TreeNode`, which is of type `TreeNodeCollection`, also has a [`Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which allows you to specify whether or not you want to search recursively or just search the direct descendents of the `TreeNode`.

Example: suppose you have a TreeNode called myTreeNode...

```
// search for the key only in direct descendents of myTreeNode
bool keyIsPresent = myTreeNode.Nodes.ContainsKey("someKey");
// value of keyIsPresent will be the same if you specify false 
// for the searchAllChildren parameter in Find
bool keyIsPresent = myTreeNode.Nodes.Find("someKey", false).Length > 0;
// value of KeyIsPresent will not necessarily be the same if you 
// specify true for the searchAllChildren parameter in Find, which is 
// recursive and will search all descendents of myTreeNode
bool keyIsPresent = myTreeNode.Nodes.Find("someKey", true).Length > 0;
```

So the `Find` method will provide you with the option of searching only direct descendents, or all descendents of the `TreeNode`.